# why do all the contacts are displayed in my Quick action?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

[image]

Always all the contacts are fetched in my LWC component which is used in Account quick action even though i used below query in my Apex class

```
select id,name,email,Is_Primary__c from contact where AccountId=:AccountId
```

A snippet from HTML file

```
<h2> Select Contacts</h2>
              <lightning-datatable data={result} columns={columns} key-field="Id">
              </lightning-datatable>
```

Snippet below for JS file

```
//Inside export part introduced a variable for recordId by using @api decorator. It will be a public access modifier.
import { LightningElement, api,track } from 'lwc';
import showContacts from "@salesforce/apex/contactHelper.fetchcontacts";
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import DESCRIPTION_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Description';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Id';


export default class RecordIdInLWC extends LightningElement {
    @track columns = [{
        label: 'Is Primary',
        fieldName: 'Is_Primary__c',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true,
        editable:true
    },{

        label: 'Name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Email',
        fieldName: 'Email',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: true
        },
    
    ];
    
    //Create a Record ID variable
    @api recordId;
    @track result; 
    @api invoke() {
        console.log("+++"+this.recordId);
    
    }

   connectedCallback(){
        console.log("+++"+this.recordId);
        showContacts({ AccountId: this.recordId })
        .then(res => {
            if (res!=null) {
                this.result = res;
                console.log("++Result++"+JSON.stringify(this.result ));
            }
        })
         .catch(error => {
            console.log('Data fetch failed', error);
            this.error = error;
          });
}
}
```

where result is the value from my apex class (list of contacts) column is the track decorator definition to hold the column attributes

if i use the same component in the record page the query works fine. What should be the problem here ?

Comment: Please update your js code also. From where you are getting the AccountId ?

Comment: What is the AccountId value? Could it perhaps be null, and this is showing contacts with a null account?

Comment: im using @api recordId to get the values I have value if i add the component in record page but if same component is added in lightning action im not getting it it shows undefined.